# How to put a text overlay on a DRM video being Airplayed to an Apple TV?

Tags: ios, swift, drm, airplay

I'm casting a DRM video from an iOS app to Apple TV, using AVPlayer.

I need to put a non-removable text overlay on top of the video while it's being played on the Apple TV player. How can I do this?

Comment: Use CATextLayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Airplay protocol for video doesn't allow overlaying anything on the video. The way the protocol works, is the Apple TV device will be asked to play the video stream, you have no control over presentation.

If you want to have overlays that are not just subtitle tracks, you need to create a tvOS app use that.

This is the case whether or not you are using DRM.